# How can I add 1 minute to current time that I get? webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I get the current time and need to add 1 minute to it so It would be 1 minute ahead, how do I do that?

```
string date1 = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: I think a simple google search could have saved you a lot of wasted time.

Comment: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=c%23+how+to+add+minutes+a+datetime&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Z-tJVqihB4ymsAGZ0qLYAw returns 240k result. Please do some research before you ask your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to use is [DateTime.AddMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 string date1 = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm");
```

Conversely, if you want to subtract a minute just use a negative parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTime.AddMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes(v=vs.110).aspx) method can do that.

If you want a string representation then do:

```
string date1 = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("HH:mm");
```

As a side note, you can also supply a negative number to subtract minutes from current time like:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1)
```